# How to monitor the memory usage of Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory

How can I monitor the memory usage of Node.js?

Answer (score 243):

The built-in [process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html) module has a method [`memoryUsage`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage) that offers insight in the memory usage of the current Node.js process. Here is an example from in Node v0.12.2 on a 64-bit system:

```js
$ node --expose-gc
> process.memoryUsage();  // Initial usage
{ rss: 19853312, heapTotal: 9751808, heapUsed: 4535648 }
> gc();                   // Force a GC for the baseline.
undefined
> process.memoryUsage();  // Baseline memory usage.
{ rss: 22269952, heapTotal: 11803648, heapUsed: 4530208 }
> var a = new Array(1e7); // Allocate memory for 10m items in an array
undefined
> process.memoryUsage();  // Memory after allocating so many items
{ rss: 102535168, heapTotal: 91823104, heapUsed: 85246576 }
> a = null;               // Allow the array to be garbage-collected
null
> gc();                   // Force GC (requires node --expose-gc)
undefined
> process.memoryUsage();  // Memory usage after GC
{ rss: 23293952, heapTotal: 11803648, heapUsed: 4528072 }
> process.memoryUsage();  // Memory usage after idling
{ rss: 23293952, heapTotal: 11803648, heapUsed: 4753376 }
```

In this simple example, you can see that allocating an array of 10M elements consumers approximately 80MB (take a look at `heapUsed`).
If you look at V8's source code ([`Array::New`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/v8/+/ba56077937e154aa0adbabd8abb9c24e53aae85d/src/api.cc#5869), [`Heap::AllocateRawFixedArray`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/v8/+/ba56077937e154aa0adbabd8abb9c24e53aae85d/src/heap/heap.cc#4092), [`FixedArray::SizeFor`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/v8/+/cb1b554a837bb47ec718c1542d462cb2ac2aa0fd/src/objects.h#2469)), then you'll see that the memory used by an array is a fixed value plus the length multiplied by the size of a pointer. The latter is 8 bytes on a 64-bit system, which confirms that observed memory difference of 8 x 10 = 80MB makes sense.

Comment: @MestreSan Which version of Node doesn't need `--expose-gc` for the `gc` function?

Comment: @MestreSan I never said that you need `--expose-gc` for `process.memoryUsage()`. `gc()` (requiring `--expose-gc`) was used in the answer to deterministically trigger garbage collection to make it easier to see what the `process.memoryUsage` reports.

Comment: That's an awesome answer to measure JS-Stuff in the right way. Thank you for that answer.

Comment: You did the lords work with this one. I just realized all the methods exposed by calling process which will help me create a more efficient application. Thanks.

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 61):

Also, if you'd like to know global memory rather than node process':

```
var os = require('os');

os.freemem();
os.totalmem();
```

[See documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_freemem)

Comment: However, freemem() is not the same as available memory on the server. Any way to find available memory rather than free?

Comment: this is the answer to another question

Comment: Seems os.freemem() uses available memory as of this issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/23892

Comment: @Alex Math.round(OS.totalmem() / 1024 / 1024 * 100) / 100-Math.round(OS.freemem() / 1024 / 1024 * 100) / 100

Answer (score 61):

You can use node.js [`process.memoryUsage()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage):

```js
const formatMemoryUsage = (data) => `${Math.round(data / 1024 / 1024 * 100) / 100} MB`;

const memoryData = process.memoryUsage();

const memoryUsage = {
  rss: `${formatMemoryUsage(memoryData.rss)} -> Resident Set Size - total memory allocated for the process execution`,
  heapTotal: `${formatMemoryUsage(memoryData.heapTotal)} -> total size of the allocated heap`,
  heapUsed: `${formatMemoryUsage(memoryData.heapUsed)} -> actual memory used during the execution`,
  external: `${formatMemoryUsage(memoryData.external)} -> V8 external memory`,
};

console.log(memoryUsage);

/*
{
  "rss": "177.54 MB -> Resident Set Size - total memory allocated for the process execution",
  "heapTotal": "102.3 MB -> total size of the allocated heap",
  "heapUsed": "94.3 MB -> actual memory used during the execution",
  "external": "3.03 MB -> V8 external memory"
}
*/
```

Comment: What exactly is data here?

Answer (score 33):

If you are using express.js framework then you can use [**express-status-monitor**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-status-monitor). Its very easy to integrate and it provides CPU usage, memory usage, response time etc in graphical format.

[image]

Comment: This is useful! To get basic insights at high level.

Answer (score 5):

On Linux/Unix (note: Mac OS is a Unix) use `top` and press M (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) to sort processes by memory usage.

On Windows use the Task Manager.

Comment: @majidarif Go to `Applications > Utilities` and you will find an `Activity Monitor` app. That one is the equivalent of Task Manager. OS X also has the `top` command as well.

Comment: use `htop` instead of top on Linux.  It's much better.