# Node.js/electron: How to Identify the process is windows process or other application process

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process

I am working on an application which gives top 5 CPU usage applications names. Currently, I have got top 5 applications from the following code:

```
    var _ = require('lodash');
    var ps = require('current-processes');

     ps.get(function(err, processes) {

        var sorted = _.sortBy(processes, 'cpu');
        var top5  = sorted.reverse().splice(0, 5); // Top 5 results

        console.log(top5);

    });
```

Output: Attaching o/p in image:
[image]

I have worked on other method as well:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
  exec('tasklist', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    var lines = stdout.toString().split('\n');
    console.log(lines);
  });
```

Output Image

[image]

But I am unable to identify whether the process(pid) is of windows services or other application. In short, I don't want to show any system service. Is there any other way to identify this?

Comment: Looks like you mixed up the screenshots.

Comment: @estus Fixed now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tasklist` is an acceptable way to do this.

System applications and services can be filtered out by `Session Name` and `Username` columns.

[`tasklist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tasklist) helper package may be used instead of parsing command output manually.

Basically `N/A` (can be localized) and `NT AUTHORITY\*` (can have local names so `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` isn't reliable) users and services (likely fall under previous category) should be filtered out:

```
tasklist({ verbose: true })
.then(apps => {
  apps = apps
  .filter(app => app.sessionName !== 'Services')
  .filter(app => /^(?!NT AUTHORITY).+\\/.test(app.username));

  console.log(apps)
})
.catch(console.error);
```

Comment: I am a little bit confused where should I put these things? really apologized for such comment, but I am new to this thing and unable to get it. Can you please add my above code as well to explain this?

Comment: As u say. I am also looking at the session. If it is a system application then it is 0 else it is 4. Can we use it for distinguishing?

Comment: You should put this to the place where you call the code. `await` should occur inside `async` function. If you don't have one, you can wrap the code with IIFE: `(async () => { ... })().catch(console.error)` or switch to regular promises. I guess `Services` session name corresponds to 0 session. I expect it to be same regardless of locale, but you can use it for safety, too. I'd suggest to address OS-specific questions at https://superuser.com/ if you have them.

Comment: I am getting errors Can you please add my code with yours and edit the answer? I am not using 'await'.

Comment: I edited it. Surely not. tasklist is Windows-specific, the question was about *windows process*. If you're after other OSes, you need to handle them separately. Check https://github.com/sindresorhus/ps-list/blob/master/index.js for how it's done. Basically it's tasklist for windows and ps for mac and linux. You can use a helper like https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps to avoid parsing `ps` output manually.

Comment: Thank you  @estus

Comment: is this memUsage is in bytes ? do you know how to get overall memory?

Comment: Yes, it's in bytes, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/tasklist for reference. By overall you mean free/used machine RAM? It's not related to processes because it's not equal to a sum of their used memory. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33145420/3731501

Comment: Thanks, I got it.

Comment: tasklist provides "imageName" is there any way to get app Name. Example: imageName= chrome.exe and name = chrome. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I believe it's windowTitle field. Consider asking at superuser.com, this is specific to `tasklist` command - and `ps` if you're trying to support *nix). I'm not proficient with them.

Comment: Sure, let me check it.