# How to monitor memory consumption by nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

My nodejs script fails with following error,

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[78:0x29f56b0]    31470 ms: Scavenge 2041.7 (2050.3) -> 2041.9 (2051.5) MB, 9.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.231, current mu = 0.213) allocation failure 
[78:0x29f56b0]    31547 ms: Scavenge 2042.8 (2051.5) -> 2042.5 (2047.8) MB, 14.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.231, current mu = 0.213) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x134e879]
Security context: 0x01e8352c0919 <JSObject>
...
```

**Now, I want to know the memory consumption by nodejs's V8 engine in runtime while my script is 
being executed. How can I do that ?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to monitor the memory usage of Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018588/how-to-monitor-the-memory-usage-of-node-js)

Comment: Hope this will be helpful - https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go with native nodejs solution you can use process.memoryUsage() function.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/memory-usage-node-js/).

I have written a small helper script for myself that returns formatted memory consumption that is easy to read (values are calculated to MBs):

```
function getMemory() {
    return Object.entries(process.memoryUsage()).reduce((carry, [key, value]) => {
        return `${carry}${key}:${Math.round(value / 1024 / 1024 * 100) / 100}MB;`;
    }, "");
};
```

The output of this function looks like this:

```
rss:282.61MB;heapTotal:239.46MB;heapUsed:129.36MB;external:22.13MB;
```

Answer (score 0):

> if you want to check for global memeory go for

```
var os = require('os');

os.freemem();
os.totalmem();
```

> or you want node specific then go for

**memwatch-next**

for tutorial [click](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/11/tracking-down-memory-leaks-in-node-js-a-node-js-holiday-season/)