# Memory efficient way to store a lot of very small arrays of integers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, performance, memory

**Edit**: sorry I will update with the latest code later assume **tmpRaw** is generated. But anyway it get out of memory similarly.
I guess this is unfeasible there is nothing to do with it. As any compression must be dealt with inside the tf-idf algorithm as anyway the whole dataset is referenced there.

By saying a lot of small arrays, I mean not storing an array of arrays but really independent references because I'm feeding a ML algorithm (tf-idf).

My data is of this sort:

`[[1115, 585], [69], [5584, 59, 99], ...]`

Practically I don't have the full data, but only a generator so each sub-array at a time.

I didn't do the complexity and memory calculations, but I'm not far from achieving the goal on a local machine (I'm processing 1/3 of data then running out of memory).

I tried the following:

`[Int32Array.from([1115, 585]), ...]` but it didn't help. Maybe typed arrays are not the best when you have small arrays.

Processing time doesn't matter a lot, as the algorithm runs pretty fast for now.

There might be a lot of repetitions of values, So I can build a dictionary but unfortunately there would be collisions with real values say for example:

> 1115 -> 1, 585 -> 2

But 1 and 2 might be allocated already in the real values fed to the tf-idf algorithm.

Finally I'm running on Node.

**Edit**

```js
for (let index = 0; index < tmpRaw.length; index++) {
    const nex = tmpRaw[index];
    // nex is like "hello world"
    try {
        // indexStrGetter simply turns "hello world" to [848,8993] using a prior dictionary
        doc = { id: co++, body: nex.map(indexStrGetter).filter(Boolean)}
        // or the following is nearly the same, (when the memory get exhausted)
      doc = { id: co++, body: Int32Array.from(nex.map(indexStrGetter)).filter(num => num > 0) }
        if (!doc.body.length) {
            co--
            continue
        }
      // BM TF-IDF is this implementation (modified a little: https://gist.github.com/alixaxel/4858240e0ca20802af43)
      bm.addDocument(doc)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        console.log(nex)
    }
}
```

Comment: one thought is to build a dictionary using the biggest values of Int32Array like from the end. But I feel I'm going far for this

Comment: Sharing your current code can be helpful

Comment: I guess this is unfeasible there is nothing to do with it. As any compression must be dealt with inside the tf-idf algorithm

Comment: Do you really need to store the whole thing in memory simultaneously?

Comment: Where does the data come from? *I didn't do the [...] memory calculations* - when you are running out of memory, it could make sense having an estimate...

Comment: By 1/3 I thought the order is fine to lookup for a solution. The data is Wikipedia titles and around 300mb before cleansing. The tf-idf model becomes a lot bigger, so why are arrays of numbers instead of strings, is because I built a dictionary already of unique words. But see my solution as I think nothing much to do about it

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that the array is the memory culprit?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018588/how-to-monitor-the-memory-usage-of-node-js for guidance on narrowing memory leaks / exhaustion...

Comment: I came to conclusion that it is mere data allocation and there is no way to compress that. Admitting I use tf-idf for my aim. For the cause it is clear that it is the array being fed to tf-idf, not inside the loop but it stacks anyway in tf-idf

Answer (score 1):

If at any given moment you need to iterate over the outer array I think that the best way to get an efficiency improvement is to generate the array inside the loop, so when each iteration ends the variable is destroyed and a lot of memory will be saved.

Comment: The sub-arrays are yielded and consumed instantly, (in the top level code inside the loop), I think it does automatically un-reference generated values (subarrays) but if and only if they are not used, but actually I use them, I feed the tf-idf algorithm with sub-arrays

Comment: This is exactly the problem , generated values are not a problem because they are generated. But you need to feed them, and then the tf-idf algorithm will store them

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 1-dimensional array and have a separator (for ex `null`)  for each sub array. Then your array will become this:

`[1115, 585, null, 69, null, 5584, 59, 99, null, ...]`

This way you will get rid of a lot of sub-array pointers

Answer (score 0):

As I have thought of it, there nothing much to do to gain memory as data just needs that minimum.

All I can do is to build sub models (tf-idf) with chunks of data. With a bit less of learning accuracy.

if Node does efficiently store same strings in a single process like showed here:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/bytefish-vs-new-string-bytefish-what-is-the-difference-a795f6a7a08b

the last optimization would be to not convert words to numbers as ive been doing.